# Z-index: neg value preventing me from targeting classes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've set many divs in my background to a z-index of -3 so that they would not interfere with the formatting of elements in the foreground. However, I also want to be able to target those background divs with jquery through on click, and now I can't seem to be able to click on them. I think this is because of other elements with higher z-indexes covering up the foreground. Is there a good solution for this?

Comment: We need to see the code... [Try the new stack snippet feature](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here).

Answer (score 0):

Its tough to say without seeing the layout of what you are trying to do but I think you're going to have to hack it. This sounds like a really abstract project... If not there is probably a much easier way. Can you post the code?

You are probably right in the a lower z-index will make it unclickable, but only if there is a transparent div or some of it's margin/padding blocking it.

Try: 
1. Right click, view source, see if you can position elements using relative positioning instead of margin and padding. Make sure the top divs are as small as possible. If you can see through it it probably doesn't need to be blocking anything.
2. Create an invisible div on top for clicking so that it looks like you're clicking on the hidden element (this is a mega hack and not best practice, or even good practice, but sometimes you just need it to work)

I'm really just guessing. If you can show us what you're working on it will be a lot easier to offer a solution!